# Probability that the maximum of $N$ numbers uniformly drawn with replacement from $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$ is unique

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I developed a Monte Carlo algorithm in which $N$ numbers $n_1,\ldots,n_N$ are drawn with replacement from $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. The algorithm has a correct outcome if the maximum of the drawn numbers is unique, (i.e. if $|\max_i\{n_1\}| = 1)$.

How can I calculate the probability of this event? I guess it has something to do with ${N}\choose{1}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the maximum value drawn with replacement is $m$ and it is only drawn once (i.e. the other $N-1$ draws are no more than $m-1$) is ${N \choose 1}\times \frac1N \times \left(\frac{m-1}{N}\right)^{N-1}$ so adding these up gives $$\sum\limits_{m=1}^N \left(\frac{m-1}{N}\right)^{N-1}$$

For $N\ge 2$ this is between $0.5$ and $0.582$

Comment: Excuse me, the values must be drawn without replacement. Forgot to specify that..

Comment: @Sven If you draw numbers without replacement than  every number drawn will be unique and so the maximum number drawn will be unique.  If you draw $N$ numbers without replacement from $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ then you will draw every number and the maximum will be $N$

Comment: Oops, of course it is with replacement..